# PHP: Is it cleaner to cast to int for calculating?

Tags: php, types, casting, type-conversion

I am writing a function that accepts a numeric string as argument, then does some calculations with it and returns it.

As you probably noted, I am doing calculations with a string. Although it works without problems in PHP, I know that other language would throw an error. That leads to my question:

Should I cast the string to an integer before my calculations, then calculate with the int and cast the result back again to a string? Would that be a cleaner style somehow? Or is it really ok to be 'type unspecific' in PHP?

Comment: There is a reason that php is a loosely-typed language.

Comment: I would say no. There's mathematical and concatenation operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll advise you to check if the arguments are numeric with [is_numeric()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.is-numeric.php). I think it's important to handle improper function calls. Also I don't see any reason to cast operands for calculation — PHP will do it for us. But I would prefer to return the result of a particular type for predictable JSON serialization or DB driver's behavior.

```
function calc($a, $b) {
    if (!ctype_digit($a) || !ctype_digit($b)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('A and B must be an integers');
    }

    return (string) ($a + $b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just a side question: Why did you type a backslash before `InvalidArgumentException`?

Comment: This is necessary when you are using [namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php). Class `InvalidArgumentException` belongs to the root namespace.

Comment: Just reread the topic title. `is_numeric` returns `true` not only for strings like `4`, but also for `4.5` and `0x56fc`. I think it will better to use [ctype_digit](http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) if your input is always a string. Just edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a loosely-typed language so you will have no trouble performing calculations with string data because the parser performs type-juggling for you.

Do note that if you are getting into very precise calculations which require extensive float accuracy then you will need to use the **[BC Math Library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)**

Answer (score 1):

From a programming perspective, it might be better to think about why you want to use numeric strings for calculations. Why not use integer input as well as integer output?